# creating a custom field in Tableau that would give me a count of the items that are still waiting on a response

Tags: date, count, tableau-api

I need assistance in creating a custom field in Tableau that would give me a count of the items that are still waiting on a response.  Below is an image of some dummy data. I need the calculation to first look at the Response Requested column. If it is "yes", then look at the Receipt Date column. If it is null, then look at the requested Response Date column. If the requested response date is past today's date, then I would like it to be added to the count.

[response dummy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuLFt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
count(IF [Response Requested] = 'Yes' and isnull([Response Receipt Date]) and [Response Date] < TODAY() then 1 end)
```

Comment: That worked! I was trying the following formula and it didn't work. Thank you!

IF [Response Requested] = 'Yes' AND [Response Receipt Date] = NULL  AND [Requested Response Date]< TODAY() THEN 1 else 0 END

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer to assist others in the future.